# Notifications by email: What are the conditions?

Tags: bug, email-notification

I'm a bit confused: I think I set my options to "no email", as I *normally* don't get any SE notifications (I visit Chess SE almost daily, so the indicator on the upper right of the homepage suffices for me). Lately (say, since a month or so), the one or other comes through. And I don't see any pattern. Not on action (comment, closure, ...), not on sub-SE. (Maybe the executor of the action plays a role?)

Anybody have an idea what is going on? (I tagged as "bug", but it's not even a nuisance due to me producing not that much traffic on SE. Other, though, might be interested to know.)

EDIT: I see that my inbox is set to "Daily on", but as I said, I never got those emails before, thus some automatic change must have happened. Moreover, this would imply that I get *all* reminders. But for example, I did not get a reminder about the two comments below (yet!), and this is the first comment (also got two "Closed") reminder on SE ever:

```
3 new items in your Stack Exchange inbox
# Have any tournaments considered a draw to be a loss for both sides?
### comment | May 7 at 13:38
```

(A near lying assumption is to blame my email, but the university spam filter is very mild, I myself have none and the mailbox is very reliable, so either I should get *all* or *none*.)

I keep it set to "on" and watch that for a while. I can always set it to "off" but a fraction of the reminders would be a bug either...

Comment: Did you check your settings here: https://chess.stackexchange.com/users/email/settings/current ?

Comment: What's in the e-mail? Are they notifications, newsletters, blog posts or something else entirely?

Comment: @Mast pretty sure OP talks only about [such emails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqMQg.png), I also found them very unstable when trying it out. Since I don't really need them I didn't post anything, but agree with OP that it feels buggy.